# Building a REST API on top of custom rolled php framework

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

A while back we developed a web application to allow users to place and track orders.  We would now like to add a REST api to allow desktop software to place orders, check status, etc.

I've looked around the web a lot to get an idea of where to move ahead.  My big hang up is with authentication, for both the app, and for certain calls, a specific user.

Should app authentication data be sent as a header for all calls? (I've looked at doing something like [AWS' authentication](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html) but how do you access the Authentication header in PHP?  Or could I use custom heads, ie X_MYAPP_AUTH.  Is that bad practice?)

For user authentication, should I have them pass the users login credentials on each call?  Or on an initial call to generate a user token of some sort?  Or should I do a full OAuth sort of implementation, but that seems like a lot of overhead.

We would be willing to use a library that would work well with our current framework, but many that I've looked at list only apache compatibility and we are running on IIS7.  Also, we will deploy sepearte instances of this api for each of our clients, so any framework would need to be easily re-deployable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, do it the same way you usually do in a web application.

You call a login API method with Username and Password when the user starts his desktop application, if the user successfully logs in you return a session token that the user keeps until it expires.

This session token is used for all the API calls the user will do in the future, f.x. place order or check status.